# SQL Direct Reference to Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way in Microsoft SQL to reference a specific item of data based on table, column and record?

For example, table A (COL1 INT, COL2 INT) has 2 records (1,2) and (3,4). Can I somehow capture value 4 by reference, rather than as "4"?

The purpose is to allow me to create an audit method that can point to specific value in a (table, column, record) without having to duplicate that value in my audit table (which could be large, therefore bloating my database size).

I am thinking ... just like Object_Id identifies a particular SQL object, so would this reference (some kind of GUID, perhaps?) identify a specific piece of data.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: a GUID could be more space waisting then your actual value. But more important, what is it you want to store in the audit table ? A changed value ? The original value ? If you want a reference to both values then you need to store the original value anyway, where else would your reference point to ?

Comment: Each time a change is made, new record is created in the table that was changed. So if I can store a pointer to original value and to the new value, I can easily present a report of before-after changes, without having to query them individually from the table.

Furthermore, as my audit would cover multiple tables, creating a query that would cover everything dynamically would require dynamic-sql, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: I strongly recommend not using the same audit table to cover multiple tables. How can you store a pointer to the original value after it has changed ?

Comment: Each change in audited table will not overwrite the original record, but instead mark it as "inactive" and create a new record with changed values. So the original record and new record will both exist in the table.

Comment: so you are using the actual table also as audit table ? Are you not worried that your table will become slow because it will grow significant with audit data ?

Comment: So if I do 10 changes in table1 on the same row then there will be 11 rows in table1 for that row ?

Comment: Yes. This is also in line with there needing to be a historical record maintained for that table.

Comment: but you are bloathing your actual table with audit data, making it slower and slower. And you have to add columns to your row that are not needed for actual rows, like datetime of an update for example. There is a reason to put audit data in separate tables

Comment: I advise making an audit table for each auditable table, so you dont need to add extra columns to your actual table, and so your actual table can stay fast.

Comment: So that 10 updates on the same row, will cause 10 rows in the audit table, and just one row in the actual table

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. In MS SQL (and, as far as I know in other popular databases) there are no such references to specific values.
Moreover, even table rows in MS SQL do not have embedded unique identifiers, unless you take care to create an IDENTITY column.

You can yourself make the implementation of such references. For example, create a table with columns

```
data_id,
table_name,
row_id,
column_name
```

and fill it up every time you need a reference. Then you can refer to piece of data by data_id.

But this is not a good solution.

- in most cases, a single entry in this table will consume more space
  than the referenced data value itself
- to get the values ​​you still have to use dynamic sql
- this will only work for tables that have an IDENTITY column and it
  has the same name for all tables
- and so on